# Did you forget to register or load this tag? - Django

Tags: python, django

I know this error is thrown usually when there's a syntax error, but I can't figure it out.

Here's my error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 3: 'reddit_tag_test', expected 'endautoescape'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Here's my code:

```
{% block content %}{% load reddit_tag_test %} {% for id in id_list %}
<div class="mdl-card__media">
  {% autoescape off %} {% reddit_tag_test id %}{% endautoescape %} {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
<script
  async
  src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js"
  charset="UTF-8"
></script>
```

I'm basically trying to embed reddit posts on my page. So I think this line

```
{% reddit_tag_test id %}
```

is causing the error, but can't figure out why. I'm passing a post id to the **reddit_tag_test** function in the reddit_tag_test.py template tag file. It should be spitting out raw html which appears on the page.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you share the code/files where you have defined your custom tag?

Comment: Does reddit_tag_test.py contain the code needed to register the tag?   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I didn't have my tag registered.